# How to avoid saving of duplicated value by update

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, duplicates

I'm trying to implement update function with duplicate check.
Until now I can check if there are some duplicates in my DB, but by updating record I can insert 2 duplicates into DB and only if I will try to add a third one it will be an error.

Does anybody know how to check updated value and show message beforew saving that there is a duplicate?

My MVC controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateEvent(int id, Event e)
    {

        using (EventsDBEntities db = new EventsDBEntities())
        {
            Event eupt = db.Events.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            List<Event> evts = db.Events.Where(x => x.Title == e.Title).ToList();
            
            if(evts.Count > 1)
            {
                return Json(new { data = e, success = false, error = "Order number already exists" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                
            }
            eupt.Title = e.Title;
            eupt.Description = e.Description;
            eupt.Location = e.Location;
            eupt.color = e.color;
            eupt.fullDescription = e.fullDescription;
            eupt.Address = e.Address;
            eupt.Contact = e.Contact;
            eupt.FbFSE = e.FbFSE;
            eupt.FbMat = e.FbMat;
            eupt.FbDel = e.FbDel;
            eupt.FbCinfo = e.FbCinfo;
            eupt.FbTask = e.FbTask;
            eupt.FbCsutisfact = e.FbCsutisfact;
            eupt.Comments = e.Comments;
            eupt.TaskType = e.TaskType;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(new { data = e, success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

if I will set  if(evts.Count > 0), I will not be able to update my record, but if it will be  if(evts.Count > 1), it will be possible to add 2 same values. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious way to solve this is of course simply defining a UNIQUE constraint on your Title-column. That is the way I usually would expect this kind of requirement to be implemented. Let the database do what it's for.

However, *if* you really want to do this in your code, if you update everything but your title,

```
List<Event> evts = db.Events.Where(x => x.Title == e.Title).ToList();
```

Will get you the record you want to update. This is not what you want, because you want all records with such a title, *other than the record you want to update*. Also, consider using a meaningful variable name and avoid casting things to lists when you don't need it:

```
var duplicate = db.Events.Where(x => x.Id != id && x.Title == e.Title).Any();
```

Now you if-statement becomes self-explaining:

```
if(duplicate)
{
    return Json(new { data = e, success = false, error = "Order number already exists" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

On a side note, you check for a duplicate *Title*, but tell the user about a duplicate *Order number*. That seems strange...

Comment: Works! Thank You so much! Yes, it's strange with propertiy names. they thougt in the begining, they want to show title, but then they've realized: "oh, it's nothing but an order number". Some customers are craaaaaaaazyyyyyy XD